# GRASS Add Vector Point

Tags: grass-gis, vector, point

I need to do a viewshed analysis using GRASS. I've got the DEMs loaded; and I simply want to input several (2-4) points (like 41.12345N, 122.34567W from GPS). What is the simplest, most straightforward, way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1):

Please check the manual page of v.in.ascii to import points or GPS import (just see all import options in Menu -> File -> Import.

However, for r.viewshed you give the coordinate pair simply as parameter.

If you want to calculate several viewsheds, run it in a loop via a script.